# Що таке "Тугаєві гори"?

Tags: значення-слів, означення

У поемі "Поет" Тодося Осьмачки:

> Давно з криниці напоїли скот,
>
> за **Тугаєві гори** сонце сіло,
>
> і підвели до зоряних висот
>
> тумани сиві волохате тіло,

Що таке "Тугаєві гори"?

Знайшов полководця [Тугай-Бея](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B9-%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B9). Думав, якась гора на його честь. Знайшов ще [тугайні ліси](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%97). Знайшов ще гору "[Тугую](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8F_(%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0))".

Але все це символізує або й фактично перебуває на сході, коли сонце сідає, заходить на заході.

Допоможіть зрозуміти, будь ласка, що то за такі "Тугаєві гори". Може, я знайшов відповідь, а треба лише змінити кут зору (Осьмачка сидів десь східніше за кордон Росії з Казахстаном?)?

[Знайшов](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C_%D0%9E%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0#%D0%97_%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%82%D1%8F), що його засилали у Свердловськ (припускаю, що сучасний Єкатеринбург), Бутирку, але досі не до кінця розумію, про які гори він пише.

Answer (score 2):

Гадаю, що це якісь гори, що знаходяться на Черкащині и десь поблизу:

По-перше, у творі є багато географічних назв з цієї місцевості - [річка Рось](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C), [село Сигнаївка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0), [село Ташлик](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA), Руда гора тощо.

По-друге, сам автор із Черкащини, а згідно до [критики](https://pidruchniki.com/kulturologiya/osmachka_todos_stepanovich):

> 1947 р. написав поему "Поет" — автобіографічний твір, який присвятив
>   батькові.

І гадаю, що ви праві і швидше за все "Тугаєві гори" пов'язані із Тугай-беєм. Можливо, ця назва пов'язана із Охматівською битвою, яка відбулася на Черкащині і в якій приймав участь Тугай-бей.

Також слід врахувати, що на Черкащині справді є багато гір. Наприклад, [Мошногори](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B6) та [Канівські гори](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8).